# how to compare two different data table have same named column using loop in sql proceduer c#?

Tags: c#, sql

i have 2 data table have same column and contain value.I want to compare data from both table and find the missmatching data in another table 2.Both table contain 38 column each.

Comment: Some sample data and wanted result please!

Comment: not up to result yet..I have two tables Table 1-Column x,y,z and table 2 colomn x,y,z like wise wit data

Comment: Table1 data: A, A, B, C. Table 2 data: A, B, B. D. Expected result?

Comment: A=A TRUE,A=B FALSE LIKEWISE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select 
CASE WHEN t1.value = t2.value THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS Result
From Table1 t1
Inner Join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: used in case when  u have to compare only one column from table 1 and table 2.as fallows.SELECT hr.ID,
CASE WHEN hd.NAME=hr.NAME OR hd.ID=hr.ID THEN 'RIGHT' ELSE 'Wrong' END AS Error
FROM name hr 
FULL JOIN suname hd ON hr.IMGID=hd.IMGID
WHERE convert(date,hr.INSERT_TIME)=convert(date,getdate())

Comment: But my table1 is contain 38 column and table 2 also.How to use loop in stored proceduer in sql.

Comment: Are you saying you dont have an ID column?